# Configuring dsync between two dovecot instances for only one single user?

Tags: dovecot

In case my reading of [Replication with dsync](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/replication/) is correct, the
goal of syncing the folders for one user between two mail servers should be obtainable by ensuring *userdb* returns `noreplicate` for all but one user, or only sets `mail_replica` for the one interesting user. I've attempted doing both, as shown below.

Setting `auth_debug = yes` indicates these fields are getting picked up, regardless if I use sqlite or lua for the *userdb*. The config below, heavily inspired by [Lua based authentication](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/lua_based_authentication/), is cleaner than the sqlite one and the relevant parts goes:

```
passdb {
  driver = pam
}

userdb {
  driver = lua
  args = file=/etc/dovecot/userdb.lua blocking=yes
  result_success = return-ok
}

userdb {
  driver = passwd
  skip = found
}
```

```lua
---@diagnostic disable: lowercase-global,undefined-global
local syncuser = "someuser"

function auth_userdb_lookup(req)
  local fields = "uid=" .. req.user .. " " ..
      "gid=mail " ..
      "home=/home/" .. req.user .. " " ..
      "mail=maildir:/var/mail/%u"
  if req.user == syncuser then
    return dovecot.auth.USERDB_RESULT_OK, fields ..
        -- might be invalid syntax, but we're not getting this far...
        " mail_replica=remote:user@other.server"
  else
    return dovecot.auth.USERDB_RESULT_OK, fields ..
        " noreplicate=yes"
  end
end

function script_init()
  return 0
end

function script_deinit()
end

function auth_userdb_iterate()
  return {syncuser}
end
```

My expectation from the above would be that sync attempts only happened for
*someuser*, but `doveadm log errors` quickly gets flooded with (for other users than *someuser*):

> Error: doveadm(…): sync: User has no mail_replica in userdb

I would also expect `doveadm user '*'` to only show *someuser* as that is the only value returned by `auth_userdb_iterate()`, but it does instead give me all users on the system.

The lua code uses the recommended [Dovecot Settings Types](https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/types/?highlight=boolean#boolean) kind of boolean, as it makes most sense. I've tried [lua style](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.2.html) *true* and *1* too, with no difference in the outcome.

While I realize the error message comes from [doveadm-dsync.c](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/main/src/doveadm/doveadm-dsync.c#L1044), it does seem a bit misdirected to dive that deep into the internals for something that is perhaps only a simple misconception on my side?